# Trying to make a macro to gets user input, search for the column header, then sort the data based on the input in ascending order

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro that will ask an user for an input, search for that column header (which will be the first row), then once found, it will add a filter and sort the data, hopefully preserving data integrity (I don't want it to only sort the one column). Seems to work ok up until I have my sort function, I keep getting an error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim PutInput As Range
Dim UserPut As String

UserPut = Application.InputBox("Select Unique ID", Type:=2)

Set PutInput = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:=UserPut, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)

If Not PutInput Is Nothing Then
Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=PutInput.Column

Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Sheet1[[#All],["& PutInput &"]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,
 Order:=xlAscending

Else
MsgBox "No match found."
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  There's a few things going on.  First, when you set the key, just use the PutInput range directly instead of trying to manually construct the range.  Also, you need to check if the autofilter is turned on already (or just leave out the sht.autofilter part entirely, but then somebody can just turn them off and break your code.  Things will be simpler if you set a worksheet object and assign the sheet to that once, instead of referring to it multiple times.

Let me know how this works for you.

```
Sub filterIt()

    Dim PutInput As Range
    Dim UserPut As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    UserPut = Application.InputBox("Select Unique ID", Type:=2)
    
    Set PutInput = sht.Rows(1).Find(What:=UserPut, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
    
    If Not PutInput Is Nothing Then
    
        If sht.AutoFilterMode = False Then sht.UsedRange.AutoFilter
        sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        
        sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
            Key:=PutInput.Columns(1), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            
        With sht.AutoFilter.Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
            End With
    
    Else
    
        MsgBox "No match found."
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Chris, this helped a lot and is getting me what I need. Thank you so much!